# How to Set DataGridView Image Cell Style to Stretch?

Tags: c#

I want to stretch the images displayed in a DataGridView column:

[image: Photo]

Trying to cast the last column as `DataGridViewImageColumn` with

```
((DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns.GetLastColumn()).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Misses some `DataGridViewStatesElements` arguments!

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure the `AutoSizeMode` refers to the “column”… not the image in the column. Try…

```
imgCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
```

Comment: Thank you, It works, `((DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.Columns.Count-1]).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;`